# Link to plotly object

Tags: python, plotly-python

At the moment, when I execute the code, I automatically draw a graph in my browser. I want a link to be shown in the console instead. Only after clicking on the link will the graph be drawn in the browser

```
import ccxt
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import time

# collect the candlestick data from Binance
binance = ccxt.binance()
trading_pair = 'LTC/BTC'
startdate = int(round(time.time() * 1000))-1000*60*50
print(startdate)
candles = binance.fetch_ohlcv(trading_pair, '1m', since=startdate)
print(candles)
dates = []
open_data = []
high_data = []
low_data = []
close_data = []
# format the data to match the charting library
for candle in candles:
    dates.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(candle[0] / 1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
    open_data.append(candle[1])
    high_data.append(candle[2])
    low_data.append(candle[3])
    close_data.append(candle[4])
# plot the candlesticks
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=dates,
                       open=open_data, high=high_data,
                       low=low_data, close=close_data)])
fig.show()
```

I want something like `print(link(fig.show())` instead of `fig.show()` in the end

Answer (score 0):

You can save your plot into HTML file and then create a hyperline to this HTML file as follows:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import IPython.display as disp

fig = go.Figure(data=[{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar'}])

html_file = pyo.plot(fig, auto_open=False)

disp.HTML(f'<a href="{html_file}" target="blank_">Click here for the plot</a>')
```

**Output:**
[image]